# Download an xml file rss feed Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, rss, feed

I have a file in my project called xamarin home where it is empty. I want to download my rss feed and subscribe to the inicio.xml file with the rss feed materials

imagem

[image]

rss feed

http://pox.globo.com/rss/g1/brasil/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XDocument rss = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(url);

rss.Save(filepath);
```

Note that the contents of an Android app package are not writable - you will need to write to one of the user writable documents folders, or external storage.

Comment: Yes, and to write this inside the inicio.xml file

Comment: Thanks for the help, is it not possible to even increase this? Subscribe xml file inside project

Comment: No, this is a fundamental restriction in Android and iOS.  Is there any reason you must use a file located in your project folder, as opposed to a writable document folder?

Comment: I'm going to change the logic of my project, do what, thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can read a file from the project.  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/

Comment: How do I get the path to my mobile project ?

Comment: you don't need the path for reading an Asset - use AssetManager